# Docker compose lables constraint:node not work

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Docker swarm culster , and this is `$ docker info`

```
[dannil@ozcluster01 ozms]$ docker info 
Containers: 15
 Running: 10
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 32
Server Version: swarm/1.2.5
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 ozcluster01: 192.168.168.41:2375
  └ ID: CKCO:JGAA:PIOM:F4PL:6TIH:EQFY:KZ6X:B64Q:HRFH:FSTT:MLJT:BJUY
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 8 (6 Running, 0 Paused, 2 Stopped)
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 192 MiB / 3.79 G
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-11-04T09:24:29Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.10.3
 ozcluster02: 192.168.168.42:2375
  └ ID: 73GR:6M7W:GMWD:D3DO:UASW:YHJ2:BTH6:DCO5:NJM6:SXPN:PXTY:3NHI
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 7 (4 Running, 0 Paused, 3 Stopped)
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 192 MiB / 3.79 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-11-04T09:24:14Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.10.3
```

Then I exec `docker-compose up -d` to run my docker containers with 
lables `constraint:node==ozculster02`

but the container still start up on ozculster01.

and this is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672"
  config-service:
  image: ozms/config-service
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/configs:/var/tmp/
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    labels:
     - "affinity:image==ozms/config-service"
  eureka-service:
    image: ozms/eureka-service
    ports:
     - "8761:8761"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    labels:
     - "constraint:node==ozcluster02"
    environment:
     - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
```

Comment: hey stackoverflow, answer mans question!

Answer (score 2):

in compose v3 you should put `constraint` not in `labels` section, it shold be `deploy` section

```
services:
  ...
  eureka-service:
   ...
   deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==ozcluster02
```

see more at 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/